# Updating dynamic dplyr (R) fun_ function

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having a hard time updating a lambda function in my code because it is using a depreciated dplyr function "fun_".

I have attached a reproducible version of the error.

```
lags      = 1:10
lag_names = function(namer){paste(namer, formatC(lags, width = nchar(max(lags)), flag = "0"), sep = "_")} 
  
data.frame(Week = 1:12, Obj = 1:12, grouping = "Lagger") %>%     
    group_by(grouping)  %>%
    mutate_at(vars(Obj ), funs_(setNames(paste("dplyr::lag(., ", lags, ")"), lag_names("Obj _Lagged"))))
```

I have tried updating the code to:

```
  data.frame(Week = 1:12, Obj = 1:12, grouping = "Lagger") %>%     
    group_by(grouping)  %>%
    mutate_at(vars(Obj ), list(setNames(paste("dplyr::lag(., ", lags, ")"), lag_names("Obj _Lagged"))))
```

But that does not work.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Your old code does not run.

Comment: Corrected it. They should both run now. Thank you. @MichaelDewar

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

lags      = 1:10
string_length <- lags %>% str_length() %>% max

df <- data.frame(Week = 1:12, Obj = 1:12, grouping = "Lagger") %>%     
    group_by(grouping) %>% 
    arrange(Week) # Just to be safe

for(n in seq_along(lags)){
    string <- lags[[n]] %>% str_pad(width = string_length, pad = "0")
    
    df <- df %>% mutate("Obj _Lagged_{{string}}" := lag(Obj, lags[[n]]))
}

# I don't know how to stop mutate from putting " around new column names:
df %>% rename_with(~str_remove_all(., "\""))
```

If you want to avoid an explicit `for` loop, here is a purrr-style solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

lags      = 1:10
string_length <- lags %>% str_length() %>% max

df <- data.frame(Week = 1:12, Obj = 1:12, grouping = "Lagger") %>%     
    group_by(grouping) %>% 
    arrange(Week) # Just to be safe

add_one_lag <- function(lag, data = df, str_len = string_length){
    string <- lag %>% str_pad(width = str_len, pad = "0")
    
    data <- data %>% mutate("Obj _Lagged_{{string}}" := lag(Obj, lag))
    
    return(data)
}

lags %>% 
    map(add_one_lag) %>% 
    reduce(left_join, by = c("Week", "Obj", "grouping")) %>% 
    rename_with(~str_remove_all(., "\""))
```

Comment: Thanks for the proposal. 
I was really hoping to avoid the loop but I guess it's inevitable.

Comment: See my edited answer for a purrr-style solution that avoids an explicit for loop